# magento compiler not Enabled

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have got  issues with Magento compiler . Previously I was able to compile (Run compilation~) but the compiler was not getting enabled . So I gave 777 to includes folder. This did not work ,later to fix this I deleted the includes folder and then re created back.
This did not work either . Now when ever I enable Includes folder it gives a Internal server error and when I rename includes folder the site is back no Error  .

1 I can't see RUN COMPILATION Button in Backend ? and cannot enable or disable compilation.
2 tried to comment out the 2 lines of includes/config.php , No luck! 
Includes folder and directory and files of it has 777 permission enabled .

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of Research my self I did manage to fix it . Actually I had APC installed and because of this compilation was not getting enabled. Anyways as soon as I disabled APC cleared  cache,  compilation seems to be fine !
Thanks for any help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly looks like permission issue.  Though, I am not sure why its not working in your case.  Have you tried :Magento Cleanup".  If not then try it.  It is very useful for the permissions issue.

Download the file from https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions and run the php file after putting it onto the Magento root folder.

Hope this helps.